# FOP Error Says HTML File Needs Matching End Tag Even Though It Already Does

Tags: html, pdf, apache-fop

I am currently using Apache FOP to create a PDF version of an HTML file. The file itself has already been prepped with various fo tags, but when I try to execute FOP using the command line (fop -fo NoteBook.html -pdf test.pdf), I receive an error saying "the element type 'META' must be terminated by the matching end-tag ''". It is specifically referring to the tag . After doing a complete search of the file, I found the closing tag . What could cause FOP to give this kind of error?

Note: I am very limited on sharing actual code from this program.

Comment: Maybe you need strict html/xhtml, but I don't know about fop

Comment: Some intervening tag is likely unmatched. Tags have to be properly nested as well as closed. It's impossible to say without seeing your HTML, but when you say you have to do a "complete search of the file," it sounds as if there's a lot of intervening HTML.

Comment: It's about 9,000 lines of code. The thing is though, this code is also used to create a note book of sorts in a web browser and works fine.

Comment: Web browsers are more forgiving and less strict than XML applications. Your FO file is simply not well-formed XML. That's all one can say without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is probably due to the fact that your HTML file is not valid XML, so it cannot be parsed.

For example `<meta name="description" content="a book">` is correct HTML, but in order to be valid XML it should either be `<meta name="description" content="a book"/>` or `<meta name="description" content="a book"></meta>`.

However that is just the tip of the iceberg, as the real problem is that
**FOP does not accept an HTML file as input**; it accepts either:

- an FO file conforming to the [XSL-FO specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/)
- or an XML file + an XSLT stylesheet producing an FO result (just for the users' convenience, as the stylesheet transformation is done using a library, not directly by FOP)

If you have an HTML file and want to produce a PDF with FOP, you must find or develop a tool to convert it into an FO file. In particular, if you choose to use an XSLT transformation you must make sure the input is valid XML.

Comment: You were correct about me using an HTML when I should b using an FO or a combination of an XML and XSLT. I've been able to create the FO file, but when I try to turn it into a PDF, the same error persists. However, you did answer my question so I probably shouldn't use this post any further.

Comment: @Sir_Muffin META is not a valid FO element, if you have it in your FO file there is probably something wrong with the XSLT.